# loop device does not auto detach on umount

Tags: centos, redhat, mount, loop-device

I have a backup script in which I umount a squashfs file, I do backup then mount it back again. A simplified version of the script is:

```
umount /home/backup/auto/mnt/os
mksquashfs /src-dir /home/backup/auto/os.sqfs.img
mount -t squashfs -o loop /home/backup/auto/os.sqfs.img /home/backup/auto/mnt/os
```

The idea is to have access at all times to backedup data.

And this worked for long time. However I got an error of not having enough loopback devices and I saw that umount does not detach loop devices mounted with mount anymore.

Lately I had two major changes:

1. I updated the kernel to 2.6.32-754.11.1.el6.i686
2. I moved the OS to an SSD.

I just noticed that there is new kernel update 2.6.32-754.12.1.el6, so I updated, but it did not fix the problem.

OS: CentOS 6.10 i686

**Update:**
This is on the faulty system:

```
# strace -e trace=ioctl,mount mount -t squashfs -o loop os.sqfs.img mnt/os
ioctl(3, LOOP_GET_STATUS, {number=0, offset=0, flags=0, name="/home/squash/web.img", ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, LOOP_GET_STATUS, {number=0, offset=0, flags=0, name="/home/squash/web.img", ...}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
ioctl(4, LOOP_SET_FD, 0x3)              = 0
ioctl(4, LOOP_SET_STATUS64, {offset=0, number=0, flags=0, file_name="/home/backup/auto/os.sqfs.img", ...}) = 0
mount("/dev/loop1", "mnt/os", "squashfs", MS_MGC_VAL, NULL) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++

# cat /etc/mtab|grep 'mnt/os'
/dev/loop1 /home/backup/auto/mnt/os squashfs ro,relatime 0 0

# ls -la /etc/mtab
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 12 Apr 17 02:53 /etc/mtab -> /proc/mounts

# notice that here there is no even the umount call. Am I missing something?
# strace -e trace=ioctl,umount,mount umount mnt/os
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

And this is on another system with the same version of everything, but it's 64 bit:

```
# strace -e trace=ioctl,mount mount -t squashfs -o loop os.sqfs.img mnt/os
ioctl(3, LOOP_GET_STATUS, {number=0, offset=0, flags=0, name="/storage/backup/auto/home.sqfs.img", ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, LOOP_GET_STATUS, {number=1, offset=0, flags=0, name="/storage/backup/auto/mail.sqfs.img", ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, LOOP_GET_STATUS, {number=1, offset=0, flags=0, name="/storage/backup/auto/mail.sqfs.img", ...}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
ioctl(4, LOOP_SET_FD, 0x3)              = 0
ioctl(4, LOOP_SET_STATUS64, {offset=0, number=0, flags=0, file_name="/storage/backup/auto/os.sqfs.img", ...}) = 0
mount("/dev/loop2", "mnt/os", "squashfs", MS_MGC_VAL, NULL) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++

# strace -e trace=ioctl,umount,mount umount mnt/os
umount("/storage/backup/auto/mnt/os", 0) = 0
ioctl(3, LOOP_CLR_FD)                   = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++

# losetup -a
/dev/loop0: [0904]:35656625 (/storage/backup/auto/home.sqfs.img)
/dev/loop1: [0904]:35656626 (/storage/backup/auto/mail.sqfs.img)
```

I don't see LO_FLAGS_AUTOCLEAR on the good system too. but I do see difference in umount.

I reinstalled `util-linux-ng` - it didn't help. There are no updates for this package and it has never been updated. Maybe it's related to the kernel. I wander why it's working just fine on the 64 bit OS. I might install a 32 bit VM to test if it'll do the same.

**-- FIX --**

The problem was that I made /etc/mtab a link to /proc/mounts during system copy using a live CD of CentOS 7 and I forgot about it. I had to re-install grub, so I chroot to the os and made the link because grub-install wasn't working. I forgot to restore it. I fixed this by:

rm -f /etc/mtab && cat /proc/mounts |grep -v rootfs > /etc/mtab

So it works now:

```
root@home auto# smount os.sqfs.img mnt/os
root@home auto# losetup -a
/dev/loop0: [0816]:7090072 (/home/squash/web.img)
/dev/loop1: [0816]:7864675 (/home/backup/auto/os.sqfs.img)
/dev/loop4: [0816]:7864569 (/home/backup/auto/web.sqfs.img)
root@home auto# umount mnt/os
root@home auto# losetup -a
/dev/loop0: [0816]:7090072 (/home/squash/web.img)
/dev/loop4: [0816]:7864569 (/home/backup/auto/web.sqfs.img)
```

Comment: It works for me on current Linux. Your system is nearing end of life anyway; you may as well upgrade.

Comment: Well it works for me too on my other centos 6 server. I don't want to upgrade. They messed up CentOS7 with this systemd overly-complicated bulsh*t. Also reinstalling/upgrading is a way to solve problems with windows. With linux I never had to do that and I don't believe it's needed now. So I'll want until I have no choice.

Comment: I see that `/etc/mtab` is a symlink on the non-working system, instead of the expected regular file. (See my answer.) Look at what type of file it is on the working system.

Comment: Well, I tried to help you but you aren't responding. I suspect you should replace that symlink with a regular file, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, it's  holiday(s) here. Just checked. you might be right. It is actually not a symlink on the working system. I didn't expect that... I still have 17 hours to grant the award, so I'll test that. Any idea why mtab suddenly became a link? I didn't touch it.

Comment: damn it ... I did touch it and I forgot. I had to re-install grub, so I had to mount rootfs. I was having troubles with grub, so I made a backup of mtab and created the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I've gathered by poking around the source for util-linux-ng 2.17.2, which was included with CentOS 6:

On kernels < 2.6.37, Linux requires that an entry be written to `/etc/mtab` for loop mounted filesystems in order to autoclear the loop device later. If `/etc/mtab` is not writable at mount time or the entry was removed from `/etc/mtab` then the loop device won't be autocleared. On kernels >= 2.6.37 the kernel remembers the loop device backing store path and it is not required to be in `/etc/mtab`.

I was able to reproduce this on CentOS 6.10 by making `/etc/mtab` immutable, with `chattr +i /etc/mtab`. Simply deleting it wasn't enough; it would be recreated with at least a partial mount table. This is not something that should happen in normal operation, so if you find this file has been set immutable you should look for an administrator mistake or a security compromise.

If `/etc/mtab` doesn't exist or is incomplete on your older Linux system, you can make a copy from `/proc/mounts`. Don't do this on modern Linux systems though, where `/etc/mtab` is instead a symbolic link to `/proc/self/mounts` left in place for backward compatibility with ancient code that expects a mount table at that location.

Comment: I guess reading sources is always the way to go!

Comment: As I thought the problem was that I replaced mtab with a link to /proc/mounts during system recovery with livecd. I forgot to restore it and of course you can't write to /proc/mounts. You were right. What confused me in the first place was `Don't do this on modern Linux systems though, where /etc/mtab is instead a symbolic link` - I thought the symlink is normal (because it was on the live cd, but the live cd was centos 7)

Comment: @NickSoft I guess I should have been more specific. CentOS 6 is no longer modern, and has the plain file, like ancient systems before it. The symlink started with CentOS 7.

Comment: Yes, you said "modern linux systems" but in my head sounded like "some linux systems". I guess I refuse to give up on CentOS 6 yet. I know I'll have to, but systemd is annoying as hell. I restart a service and I see nothing as output. how do I know I really did something ... I run apachectl configtest and instead of giving me the error it gives me a command to see the error. I run the command and I see two screens of useless junk and a single line containing the error hidden in the middle. That's why I'll squeeze my teeth and hold on to CentOS 6 as long as I can.

Comment: @NickSoft Ahh. The behavior you describe sounds like Apache 2.4, rather than CentOS specific. For my own stuff I abandoned Apache for nginx way back when CentOS 5 was brand new. I haven't even been tempted in the slightest to go back. As for systemd, if you think it's annoying now, just wait. I found that it was so _massively_ better than its predecessors that minor annoyances like that could be overlooked.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: it appears not to be a kernel issue, but the `mount` command not behaving as expected by not setting the loop device's `LO_FLAGS_AUTOCLEAR` flag. Using a more recent out-of-distribution mount command should probably solve it.

---

Stracing a (recent system's) command mount, led me to [loop(4)](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/loop.4)'s flag `LO_FLAGS_AUTOCLEAR`:

> ```
> LO_FLAGS_AUTOCLEAR (since Linux 2.6.25)
>     The loopback device will autodestruct on last close.
> ```

So my "modern" mount command issues successfully this ioctl as seen there:

```
# strace -e trace=ioctl,mount mount -o loop /tmp/block.img /mnt/
ioctl(3, LOOP_CTL_GET_FREE)             = 0
ioctl(4, LOOP_SET_FD, 3)                = 0
ioctl(4, LOOP_SET_STATUS64, {lo_offset=0, lo_number=0, lo_flags=LO_FLAGS_AUTOCLEAR, lo_file_name="/tmp/block.img", ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, BLKGETSIZE64, [1073741824])    = 0
ioctl(3, CDROM_GET_CAPABILITY, 0)       = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
ioctl(3, BLKSSZGET, [512])              = 0
mount("/dev/loop0", "/mnt", "ext4", MS_MGC_VAL, NULL) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
# umount /mnt
# losetup -l
#
```

(The losetup syntax here differs from CentOS6).

I thought if the issue is not in the kernel (since OP's 2.6.32 > 2.6.25), it could be from the mount command. To check, I installed a centos6-i686 LXC container, installed strace, created the missing /dev/loop* files and ran a totally privilegied shell inside (using `lxc-attach`'s `-e` option) allowed to perform mount operations:

```
# lxc-attach -e -n centos6-i686
[root@centos6-i686 ~]# cat /etc/centos-release 
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/block.img bs=1 count=1 seek=$((2**30-1))
[...]
# ls -lh /tmp/block.img 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1.0G Apr 22 19:06 /tmp/block.img
# mkfs.ext4 /tmp/block.img 
[...]
# strace -e trace=ioctl,mount mount -o loop /tmp/block.img /mnt/
ioctl(3, LOOP_GET_STATUS, {number=0, offset=0, flags=0, name="", ...}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
ioctl(4, LOOP_SET_FD, 0x3)              = 0
ioctl(4, LOOP_SET_STATUS64, {offset=0, number=0, flags=0, file_name="/tmp/block.img", ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, BLKGETSIZE64, 1073741824)      = 0
ioctl(3, CDROM_GET_CAPABILITY or SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_UNSUBSCRIBE_PORT, 0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
mount("/dev/loop0", "/mnt/", "ext4", MS_MGC_VAL, NULL) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
# umount /mnt
# losetup --show /dev/loop0
/dev/loop0: [003f]:1756539 (/tmp/block.img)
# losetup -d /dev/loop0
#
```

Clearly the ioctl wasn't issued with the clear flag and this caused the loop device leak. Looking at the sources, it appears this feature has been around for a long time, and is present in util-linux 2.17.2 (CentOS6's version). CentOS6's `man mount` even tells:

> Since Linux 2.6.25 is supported auto-destruction of loop devices and then any loop device allocated by mount will be freed by umount independently on /etc/mtab.

So I don't know why it didn't work, and it appears to be a bug (or this could be related to my environment: 64bits kernel 5.0.x etc.).

Comment: Thanks for finding LO_FLAGS_AUTOCLEAR. This, while not a complete answer, is a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: I had an example poc to tweak the ioctl with a wrapper but it randomly didn't behave well so I removed it. It has nothing to do in production environment anyway.